# Ruby web scraper not the same as browser result

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I have created a simple ruby web scraper to get a value from a website, but the result is not the same as is show in the browser.

Website: https://www.lme.com/Metals/Non-ferrous/Aluminium#tabIndex=0 I'm trying to get the 3-month (BID (US$ / TONNE) value from the first table.

```rb
lme_url = "https://www.lme.com/en-GB/Metals/Non-ferrous/Aluminium#tabIndex=0"
lme_unparsed = HTTParty.get(lme_url)
lme_parsed = Nokogiri::HTML(lme_unparsed)
@lme = Array.new
lme_table = lme_parsed.css('.tabContent').css('.table-wrapper')
lme_table = lme_table.css('tbody tr')
lme_table.each do |list|
  l = list.css('td').map(&:content)[1]
  @lme << l
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working using mechanize instead:

```rb
# Scrapping LME Website
lme_agent = Mechanize.new
lme_page = lme_agent.get('https://www.lme.com')
aluminum = lme_agent.page.links_with(:text => 'LME Aluminium')[1].click
lme = aluminum.xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')
@lme = lme.to_s.gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, "")
```